# Remote Desktop Connection to Azure VM terminates after connecting to Client VPN

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, azure-networking, vpn-client

I installed FortiClient VPN on my Azure VM. As soon as I connect the VPN, my Remote Desktop connection gets terminates and I can no longer reach it unless I restart the VM. I am thinking it overwrote my routing or something similar. Is there a way differentiate the connection in someway? To tell the VM once this VPN is connected then the RDP should not be broken. Anyone ever faced anything similar? In some connections with a Checkpoint VPN it is a similar process.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to re-establish your connection using the new VPN IP (assuming it allows inbound connections etc, and somehow registers it's new VPN IP somewhere for you to fetch),

OR, you can create a separate network interface to keep your RDP and VPN connections separate. In other words, RDP to your VM on eth0, but set up VPN to only use eth1.